# SSRS Expression - Line break/new line after coma in value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

One of the textbox contains a comma separated set of values as displayed below,

```
1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234
```

Existing output:

```
1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,123  
4,1234,1234,1234,1234
```

Expected output:

```
1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,
1234,1234,1234,1234,1234
```

Line should only break after coma value rather than breaking the value `1234`

I am looking for an expression to achieve that. 
Changing textbox size is not in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly confident that what you want is not possible without assuming that the values between the commas will always be the same length.

Your text is breaking in the 'middle' of a value because SSRS does not know that your commas should be treated as breaking characters, like it would a `space`.

As a result, your options are limited and depend on what the purpose of this textbox is.  If you just want to display the data, then you can worry less about how the break is defined but if you need to use this data elsewhere you *do* need to worry.

If you need to use the data elsewhere via copy and paste and you absolutely can't have the spaces you're mostly out of luck.  If you don't have to copy the data anywhere you have two options you can simply add spaces after your commas to get the breaks you want in the report:

## Option 1 - Visible Space Character

Use `replace` to swap all comma characters with a comma and a space which will show up on the report.  Whilst this may not be aesthetically desirable, at least it is obvious what is happening in the report, unlike option 2...

```
=replace(Fields!YourCol.Value, ",", ", ")
```

## Option 2 - Non-Visible Space Character

Use `replace` again, but swap the comma with a comma and a [Zero-Width Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) character.  Whilst in the report design this will be apparent, anyone trying to copy the data may get issues as there are characters present that cannot be seen.  You can see this by selecting the text *he​re*.  As you hold shift and move left and right using the arrow keys, you will notice that you need an extra press to get between `he` and `re`.

The unicode character number you need for this is `8203`, which you can use with the `ChrW` ssrs function:

```
=replace(Fields!YourCol.Value, ",", "," & chrw(8203))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is via a function that splits the line into and array of words and then 
rearrange the words in lines of a predefined size.

This function accepts two parameters, the line to split and the max size and returns a new line broken to not exceed the 
max size and without breaking the words.

Public Function splitlineaftercomma(byval line as string, linesize as integer) as string

```
dim words() as string=line.split(",") 
dim newlines() as string={""}
dim i as integer=0  
dim j as integer=0
for i=0 to words.length - 1
    if len(newline(j)+words(i)+",")>linesize then 'if the line is overflown create new line
        array.resize(newlines, newlines.length+1) 
        j+=1
    end if
    newlines(j)+=words(i)+"," 'add word plus comma to current line
next i
newlines(j)=newlines(j).trimend(",") ' remove last comma
return string.join(vbcrlf,newlines)
```

End Function

suppose your box has a size of 30 char then you can call the function as:

```
=Code.splitlineaftercomma(linetosplit,30)
```